# passenger output: /bin/sh: line 0: exec: python: not found

Tags: python, django, centos, passenger, plesk

I am trying to run a Django app. I followed https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/12377516625559.  on
Plesk Obsidian Version 18.0.41 /
Centos

When logged in with `root` or my user, `python` is aliased  and responding.

I tried adding python to any `.bashrc`

Below is a detailed of the log level 7

```
App 174090 output: + '[' -x /usr/bin/id ']'
App 174090 output: + '[' -z 10008 ']'
App 174090 output: ++ /usr/bin/id -un
App 174090 output: + USER=shlomi
App 174090 output: + LOGNAME=shlomi
App 174090 output: + MAIL=/var/spool/mail/shlomi
App 174090 output: + '[' 10008 = 0 ']'
App 174090 output: + pathmunge /usr/local/sbin after
App 174090 output: + case ":${PATH}:" in
App 174090 output: + pathmunge /usr/sbin after
App 174090 output: + case ":${PATH}:" in
App 174090 output: ++ /usr/bin/hostname
App 174090 output: + HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain
App 174090 output: + HISTSIZE=1000
App 174090 output: + '[' '' = ignorespace ']'
App 174090 output: + export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
App 174090 output: + HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
App 174090 output: + export PATH USER LOGNAME MAIL HOSTNAME HISTSIZE HISTCONTROL
App 174090 output: + '[' 10008 -gt 199 ']'
App 174090 output: ++ /usr/bin/id -gn
App 174090 output: ++ /usr/bin/id -un
App 174090 output: + '[' psacln = shlomi ']'
App 174090 output: + umask 022
App 174090 output: + for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh /etc/profile.d/sh.local
App 174090 output: + '[' -r /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh ']'
App 174090 output: + '[' hxBc '!=' hxBc ']'
App 174090 output: + . /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh
App 174090 output: ++ '[' -n '4.4.20(1)-release' -a -n '' -a -z '' ']'
App 174090 output: + for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh /etc/profile.d/sh.local
App 174090 output: + '[' -r /etc/profile.d/colorgrep.sh ']'
App 174090 output: + '[' hxBc '!=' hxBc ']'
App 174090 output: + . /etc/profile.d/colorgrep.sh
App 174090 output: ++ /usr/libexec/grepconf.sh -c
App 174090 output: ++ alias 'grep=grep --color=auto'
App 174090 output: ++ alias 'egrep=egrep --color=auto'
App 174090 output: ++ alias 'fgrep=fgrep --color=auto'
App 174090 output: + for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh /etc/profile.d/sh.local
App 174090 output: + '[' -r /etc/profile.d/colorls.sh ']'
App 174090 output: + '[' hxBc '!=' hxBc ']'
App 174090 output: + . /etc/profile.d/colorls.sh
App 174090 output: ++ '[' '!' -t 0 ']'
App 174090 output: ++ return
App 174090 output: + for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh /etc/profile.d/sh.local
App 174090 output: + '[' -r /etc/profile.d/colorxzgrep.sh ']'
App 174090 output: + '[' hxBc '!=' hxBc ']'
App 174090 output: + . /etc/profile.d/colorxzgrep.sh
App 174090 output: ++ /usr/libexec/grepconf.sh -c
App 174090 output: ++ alias 'xzgrep=xzgrep --color=auto'
App 174090 output: ++ alias 'xzegrep=xzegrep --color=auto'
App 174090 output: ++ alias 'xzfgrep=xzfgrep --color=auto'
App 174090 output: + for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh /etc/profile.d/sh.local
App 174090 output: + '[' -r /etc/profile.d/colorzgrep.sh ']'
App 174090 output: + '[' hxBc '!=' hxBc ']'
App 174090 output: + . /etc/profile.d/colorzgrep.sh
App 174090 output: ++ '[' -f /usr/libexec/grepconf.sh ']'
App 174090 output: ++ /usr/libexec/grepconf.sh -c
App 174090 output: ++ alias 'zgrep=zgrep --color=auto'
App 174090 output: ++ alias 'zfgrep=zfgrep --color=auto'
App 174090 output: ++ alias 'zegrep=zegrep --color=auto'
App 174090 output: + for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh /etc/profile.d/sh.local
App 174090 output: + '[' -r /etc/profile.d/gawk.sh ']'
App 174090 output: + '[' hxBc '!=' hxBc ']'
App 174090 output: + . /etc/profile.d/gawk.sh
App 174090 output: + for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh /etc/profile.d/sh.local
App 174090 output: + '[' -r /etc/profile.d/lang.sh ']'
App 174090 output: + '[' hxBc '!=' hxBc ']'
App 174090 output: + . /etc/profile.d/lang.sh
App 174090 output: ++ '[' -n en_US.UTF-8 ']'
App 174090 output: ++ LANG_backup=en_US.UTF-8
App 174090 output: ++ for config in /etc/locale.conf "${HOME}/.i18n"
App 174090 output: ++ '[' -f /etc/locale.conf ']'
App 174090 output: +++ /usr/bin/sed -r -e 's/^[[:blank:]]*([[:upper:]_]+)=([[:print:][:digit:]\._-]+|"[[:print:][:digit:]\._-]+")/export \1=\2/;t;d' /etc/locale.conf
App 174090 output: ++ eval export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
App 174090 output: +++ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
App 174090 output: +++ LANG=en_US.UTF-8
App 174090 output: ++ for config in /etc/locale.conf "${HOME}/.i18n"
App 174090 output: ++ '[' -f /var/www/vhosts/calendful.com/.i18n ']'
App 174090 output: ++ '[' -n en_US.UTF-8 ']'
App 174090 output: ++ LANG=en_US.UTF-8
App 174090 output: ++ unset LANG_backup config
App 174090 output: ++ '[' -n '' ']'
App 174090 output: ++ '[' -n en_US.UTF-8 ']'
App 174090 output: ++ '[' dumb = linux ']'
App 174090 output: + for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh /etc/profile.d/sh.local
App 174090 output: + '[' -r /etc/profile.d/less.sh ']'
App 174090 output: + '[' hxBc '!=' hxBc ']'
App 174090 output: + . /etc/profile.d/less.sh
App 174090 output: ++ '[' -z '' ']'
App 174090 output: ++ '[' -x /usr/bin/lesspipe.sh ']'
App 174090 output: ++ export 'LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s'
App 174090 output: ++ LESSOPEN='||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s'
App 174090 output: + for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh /etc/profile.d/sh.local
App 174090 output: + '[' -r /etc/profile.d/which2.sh ']'
App 174090 output: + '[' hxBc '!=' hxBc ']'
App 174090 output: + . /etc/profile.d/which2.sh
App 174090 output: ++ which_declare='declare -f'
App 174090 output: ++ which_opt=-f
App 174090 output: +++ cat /proc/174090/comm
App 174090 output: ++ which_shell=sh
App 174090 output: ++ '[' sh = ksh ']'
App 174090 output: ++ '[' sh = mksh ']'
App 174090 output: ++ '[' sh = zsh ']'
App 174090 output: ++ export which_declare
App 174090 output: ++ export -f which
App 174090 output: + for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh /etc/profile.d/sh.local
App 174090 output: + '[' -r /etc/profile.d/sh.local ']'
App 174090 output: + '[' hxBc '!=' hxBc ']'
App 174090 output: + . /etc/profile.d/sh.local
App 174090 output: + unset i
App 174090 output: + unset -f pathmunge
App 174090 output: + '[' -n '4.4.20(1)-release' ']'
App 174090 output: + '[' -f /etc/bashrc ']'
App 174090 output: + . /etc/bashrc
App 174090 output: ++ '[' -z '' ']'
App 174090 output: ++ BASHRCSOURCED=Y
App 174090 output: ++ '[' '' ']'
App 174090 output: ++ shopt -q login_shell
App 174090 output: + exec /usr/lib64/passenger/support-binaries/PassengerAgent spawn-env-setupper /tmp/passenger.spawn.XXXXF0ybxV --after
App 174090 output: /bin/sh: line 0: exec: python: not found
[ D 2023-10-05 07:07:00.4243 174022/Tn age/Cor/Spa/Han/Perform.h:1782 ]: [App 174090 journey] Loading state from /tmp/passenger.spawn.XXXXF0ybxV/response
[ D 2023-10-05 07:07:00.4245 174022/Tn age/Cor/Spa/Han/Perform.h:1208 ]: [App 174090 journey] Step SUBPROCESS_BEFORE_FIRST_EXEC: setting state to STEP_PERFORMED
[ D 2023-10-05 07:07:00.4245 174022/Tn age/Cor/Spa/Han/Perform.h:1419 ]: [App 174090 journey] Step SUBPROCESS_BEFORE_FIRST_EXEC: monotonic begin time is "72069.217484"
[ D 2023-10-05 07:07:00.4246 174022/Tn age/Cor/Spa/Han/Perform.h:1441 ]: [App 174090 journey] Step SUBPROCESS_BEFORE_FIRST_EXEC: monotonic end time is "72069.217484"
[ D 2023-10-05 07:07:00.4246 174022/Tn age/Cor/Spa/Han/Perform.h:1208 ]: [App 174090 journey] Step SUBPROCESS_SPAWN_ENV_SETUPPER_BEFORE_SHELL: setting state to STEP_PERFORMED
[ D 2023-10-05 07:07:00.4246 174022/Tn age/Cor/Spa/Han/Perform.h:1419 ]: [App 174090 journey] Step SUBPROCESS_SPAWN_ENV_SETUPPER_BEFORE_SHELL: monotonic begin time is "72069.217484"
[ D 2023-10-05 07:07:00.4246 174022/Tn age/Cor/Spa/Han/Perform.h:1441 ]: [App 174090 journey] Step SUBPROCESS_SPAWN_ENV_SETUPPER_BEFORE_SHELL: monotonic end time is "72069.248484"
[ D 2023-10-05 07:07:00.4246 174022/Tn age/Cor/Spa/Han/Perform.h:1208 ]: [App 174090 journey] Step SUBPROCESS_OS_SHELL: setting state to STEP_PERFORMED
[ D 2023-10-05 07:07:00.4247 174022/Tn age/Cor/Spa/Han/Perform.h:1419 ]: [App 174090 journey] Step SUBPROCESS_OS_SHELL: monotonic begin time is "72069.249484"
[ D 2023-10-05 07:07:00.4247 174022/Tn age/Cor/Spa/Han/Perform.h:1441 ]: [App 174090 journey] Step SUBPROCESS_OS_SHELL: monotonic end time is "72069.297485"
[ D 2023-10-05 07:07:00.4247 174022/Tn age/Cor/Spa/Han/Perform.h:1208 ]: [App 174090 journey] Step SUBPROCESS_SPAWN_ENV_SETUPPER_AFTER_SHELL: setting state to STEP_PERFORMED
[ D 2023-10-05 07:07:00.4247 174022/Tn age/Cor/Spa/Han/Perform.h:1419 ]: [App 174090 journey] Step SUBPROCESS_SPAWN_ENV_SETUPPER_AFTER_SHELL: monotonic begin time is "72069.287485"
[ D 2023-10-05 07:07:00.4247 174022/Tn age/Cor/Spa/Han/Perform.h:1441 ]: [App 174090 journey] Step SUBPROCESS_SPAWN_ENV_SETUPPER_AFTER_SHELL: monotonic end time is "72069.302485"
[ D 2023-10-05 07:07:00.4248 174022/Tn age/Cor/Spa/Han/Perform.h:1208 ]: [App 174090 journey] Step SUBPROCESS_EXEC_WRAPPER: setting state to STEP_IN_PROGRESS
[ D 2023-10-05 07:07:00.4248 174022/Tn age/Cor/Spa/Han/Perform.h:1419 ]: [App 174090 journey] Step SUBPROCESS_EXEC_WRAPPER: monotonic begin time is "72069.302485"
[ D 2023-10-05 07:07:00.4248 174022/Tn age/Cor/Spa/Han/Perform.h:1454 ]: [App 174090 journey] Step SUBPROCESS_EXEC_WRAPPER: no end time known
[ D 2023-10-05 07:07:00.4248 174022/Tn age/Cor/Spa/Han/Perform.h:1176 ]: [App 174090 journey] Step SUBPROCESS_WRAPPER_PREPARATION: state file does not exist
[ D 2023-10-05 07:07:00.4248 174022/Tn age/Cor/Spa/Han/Perform.h:1176 ]: [App 174090 journey] Step SUBPROCESS_APP_LOAD_OR_EXEC: state file does not exist
[ D 2023-10-05 07:07:00.4248 174022/Tn age/Cor/Spa/Han/Perform.h:1176 ]: [App 174090 journey] Step SUBPROCESS_LISTEN: state file does not exist
[ E 2023-10-05 07:07:00.4487 174022/Tn age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/www/vhosts/calendful.com/httpdocs: The application process exited prematurely.
  Error ID: a8c7780f
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-N4ZwIW.html
```

Comment: Find where python is and add the dir to PATH

Comment: You can't `exec` an alias. Why have you aliased `python` and to what? The proper fix is to make sure there is an actual `python` command; it can be as simple as `#!/bin/sh` (newline) `exec /usr/bin/python3 "$@"` - save on your `PATH` and `chmod +x` it. Alternatively, edit the Passenger script to add the full path to the `python` binary it should `exec`.

Comment: I am not sure which script to edit, /usr/lib64/passenger/support-binaries/PassengerAgent is binary.

Comment: from the log above LOGNAME=shlomi , I was assuming its logged as this user so when ssh into this user python command was missing. so created an alias. the python version in the system are v3 & v3.6. but they are not set as default. so it tired an alias

Comment: Add /usr/bin/python3.6 to the path would make it available as $ python ? the script is somewhere calling python